# ошибка "C++ отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора, соответствующие списку аргументов"

Tags: c++

```
map<string, string> DataBase {
    {'hi',"hello, hooman"},
    {"what is your name", "my name is viktor "},
    {"do you like tea", "yes, i like green tea "},

};
```

Comment: Не те кавычки: `'` -> `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема в том, что Вы записали одну из строк — `'hi'` — через *одинарные* кавычки, тогда как для строк типа `string` нужны *двойные*.

```cpp
map<string, string> DataBase {
    {"hi","hello, hooman"},
    {"what is your name", "my name is viktor "},
    {"do you like tea", "yes, i like green tea "},
};
```